# What is the typical mach number at which the peak dynamic pressure occurs?

Tags: rockets

Is there any mach number range (say 0.8-1.4) where the [maximum Q](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_q) of the rocket should occur?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It varies with the launcher design, but for most it falls somewhere between mach 1 and 2.

For the Saturn V, [max Q was about mach 1.75](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap08fj/01launch_ascent.html).

For the [space shuttle, around mach 1.3](http://www.aerospaceweb.org/question/aerodynamics/q0025.shtml).